# Updating RecyclerView by new set of data after publishing the app

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have a question that I would appreciate any on to answer.

my question is:

Is there any way to update some data like adding some videos, sales, values...etc in a recycle view after publishing the app in a google play without updating the app it self in the play store?

I actually don't have a clue on how to do this..

if there's any samples or websites on answering this question please share it with us.

thanks in advance

Comment: I assume that the data you are talking about are hardcoded in the app. You have to have a backend server providing the data via some API. Maybe googling REST and Retrofit would be a good starting point.

Comment: can you give me a link to Retrofit

Comment: https://square.github.io/retrofit/

Answer (score 1):

I can see a possibility but it's dirty, you can have one endpoint (`/recycler`), this endpoint can send you different type of data (`movies`, `book` and such), your application calls this endpoint and upon the result you parse it into one of your class that will populate your recyclerview.

I don't think you'll find any samples about it as it's not what people tends to do.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if the data you want to update is writen in you code, I believe you can't update this without update the app itself.

It seems like you need a space on you app where you want to update it easily. 
You should provide a backend to your app and consume the API to get all the info you need (with this, you will not need update the app itself on the store)

If you, like me, have no skills at backend development, give a chance to firebase:
https://firebase.google.com/

It will make easy to create a backend to your app. You'll need to update your app only once ( to make it work with firebase). After this, all you'll need to do is update you firebase, the app will get all new info from there